# OpenMP with C program

Tags: c, openmp

I am having a hard time using OpenMP with C to parallelize this method.  I was wondering if anyone could help and possibly tell me what is wrong with my parallelization of this method.

```
void blur(float **out, float **in) {
    // assumes "padding" to avoid messy border cases     
    int i, j, r, c;
    float tmp, term;
    term = 1.0 / 157.0;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
    #pragma omp for private(r,c)

    for (i = 0; i < N-4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N-4; j++) {
            tmp = 0.0;
            for (r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
                for (c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
                    tmp += in[i+r][j+c] * mask[r][c];
                }
            }
            out[i+2][j+2] = term * tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `j` needs to be private as well.

Comment: I am having hard time understanding what your problem is and what you have tried in order to fix it.

Comment: The problem is that the serial version runs a lot faster than the parallel version and I thought I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You shall either declare `tmp` inside the loop:

```
// at line 11:
float tmp = 0.0;
```

or specify `tmp` as a private variable:

```
// at line 7:
#pragma omp for private(r,c,tmp)
```

Or it would be treated like a shared variable among threads.